# Typecasting in WSO2

Tags: wso2, integration, wso2-esb, wso2-integration-studio

I have a property in my wso2 integration studio that stores the result of an arithmetic operation. The value of this property that is displayed in the logs is 12.0, how can I convert this property to integer type and make it 12?

Comment: @ycr any thoughts on how this can be done?

Comment: Check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251386/converting-double-to-integer-in-wso2-integration-studio