# Converting Double to Integer in WSO2 Integration Studio

Tags: type-conversion, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I am performing an Arithmetic operation in my XPath Expression. In the below code, qty1 and qty2 are double, hence the result I get is double. I want to convert the result to an Integer and save it in a property. How can I achieve it in WSO2 Integration Studio?

`<property name="RESULT_QTY" expression="($body/*[local-name()='Shipment']/*[local-name()='qty1'])-($body/*[local-name()='Shipment']/*[local-name()='qty2'])"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below.

```xml
<property name="double" scope="default" type="DOUBLE" value="10.0"/>
<property name="doubleString" scope="default" expression="$ctx:double" type="STRING"/>
<property expression="fn:substring-before($ctx:doubleString, '.')" name="integer" scope="default" />
```